# Lexical scope of callback function

Tags: javascript, scope, lexical-scope

could someone explain to me why startDate and endDate are not in scope in callback passed to filter function.

```
var events = [],
 eventsDataSource = [],
 statusChstatusChanges = [],
 statusChangesDataSource = [];

 function filterData() {
    var startDate = $('#start-date').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var endDate = $('#end-date').data("kendoDatePicker").value();

    events = eventsDataSource.filter(function (item) {
        debugger;
    });
    statusChanges = statusChangesDataSource.filter(function (item) {
        debugger;
    });
}
```

when I changed code to what's below it worked. starDate and endDate are in scope. Is lexical scope of callbacks/inline function created differently that function declarations?

```
function filterData() {
    var startDate = $('#start-date').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
    var endDate = $('#end-date').data("kendoDatePicker").value();

    function dateIsBetweenStartAndEnd(item) {            
        return new Date(item.Date) >= new Date(startDate) && new Date(item.Date) <= new Date(endDate);
    }

    events = eventsDataSource.filter(dateIsBetweenStartAndEnd);
    statusChanges =   statusChangesDataSource.filter(dateIsBetweenStartAndEnd);
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but it's just a guess, it's because you declare and assign `events`first (outside `filterData`), and later in `filterData` you declare `startDate` and `endDate`. It could be a problem with hoisting? Try to declare the `events` where you use it, inside the `filterData` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have some debugger statements in there.

Perhaps you are using Chrome's dev-tools and when you hit the debugger you are not able to access `startDate` and `endDate`.

**This is simply an optimization that the browser is doing** because it's not seeing any access of those functions in your code.

A quick way to verify this is to put a console statement above your `debugger` statement:

```
console.log(startDate);
debugger; // now you will be able to access startDate
```

**Your understanding of lexical scope is correct**...you are just hitting a runtime browser optimization.

For more information, see [this chrome issue report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3491).